# Azure SQL Azure AD Authentication Failure

Tags: azure, sitecore, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

I am trying to connect to my Azure SQL Database that has a Azure Active Directory Database Contained User from my .NET Application (Sitecore). I have the adalsql.dll installed on the VM hosting the .NET Application. However, when I attempt to connect, I receive the following error:

> Failed to authenticate the user test@mytest.onmicrosoft.com in Active
>   Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword). Error code
>   0xCAA20064; state 10 AADSTS50055: Force Change Password.

Here is my connectionString:

```
<add name="mydb" connectionString="Data Source=test.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=TEST_DB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=test@mytest.onmicrosoft.com;Password=12345;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=Active Directory Password" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting the user password did the trick. I had to login to the Azure Portal after going into Azure Active Directory and selecting reset password.

Comment: You will find that is you use a user account, you will continue to have this type of interrupts (e.g. require MFA, change password, risky sign-in detected, etc.). Instead, consider authenticating as an *application*, as described in the sample here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/02/09/token-based-authentication-support-for-azure-sql-db-using-azure-ad-auth/

Comment: I set the account to never expire, but you have a very valid point