# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGIN' Error 18456 Azure Sql

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

I am able to connect to my SQL Azure database using SQL Server Authentication
However when I try to use Active Directory - Universal with MFA Support I get a 18456 error.

In the Azure Portal , in Access control (IAM) I can see that the user has the owner role  and that the scope is

```
Subscription (inherited).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IAM role access only gives you management access to the resource in Azure.
SQL Server has its own access control.
You'll need to follow the instructions here to get access: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure

1. Add an AAD administrator
2. Connect with that user to the SQL instance
3. Add users/groups to roles with T-SQL

Comment: Thanks @juunas It seems that I need to set up an SQL Managed Instance which is a preview feature.  I am now waiting for my request to be approved.

Comment: Why? Regular Azure SQL supports AAD authentication.

Comment: Oops, thanks, now I am checking out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins

Comment: This link was helpful too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45243103/azure-sql-azure-ad-authentication-failure

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but in my case, it happened after I change the AAD Admin.
Initially, I'd put a specific user and changed it to a group so more people can administrate it. 
Turned out that Azure SQL Server didn't apply the change on the server correctly.

To correct the problem, I had to delete the AAD admin and include it again.